# Any possible way to check for a condition without using any of control statements in R

Tags: r, if-statement

```
if(x == y){
  text <- "string_1"
}else if(x < y){
  text <- "string_2"
}else if(x > y){
  text <- "string_3"
}
```

Is there any possible way that i could get rid of these clauses ?
Can we use any mathematical operation to find out?

Comment: `text <- switch(sign(x-y)+2, "string_2", "string_1", "string_3")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sign` to *subset* a vector for the conditions `==`, `<` and `>`.

```
text <- c("string_2", "string_1", "string_3")[sign(x-y)+2]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: Yes, you can make it without control statements.

You can try the following code

```
r <- c("string_1","string_2","string_3")[c(x==y,x<y,x>y)]
```

or

```
r <- subset(c("string_1","string_2","string_3"), c(x==y,x<y,x>y))
```

or

```
r <- c("string_1","string_2","string_3")[crossprod(diag(+c(x==y,x<y,x>y)), 1:3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a way around your problem (to me the problems seems to be the ugly code). You can write it more concise, though.

```
if(x == y) text <- "string_1"
if(x < y) text <- "string_2" 
if(x > y) text <- "string_3"
```

Comment: Am sory for not making the question clear will keep this in mind when i do next post Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` you can do:

```
library(data.table)
fcase(
  x == y, "string_1",
  x <  y, "string_2",
  default = "string_3"
)
```

As of January 2020 this feature is still only in the development version of the package.

Comment: Am restricted of using a library for this simple problem any ways thanks a lot for your valuble time